# UIView not changing position in animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have two UIViews (My bad it is a `UIView` and a `UIButton`) which I am animating at the same time. I originally had a view and a containerView which would animate just fine and worked like a charm.

Now only one of my UIViews will move/animate in animateWithDuration even though through debugging the frame of the other view says that it is in a position it is not.

```
    CGRect rect = self.toggle.frame;
    CGRect tabRect = self.tabButton.frame;
    rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x - rect.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%f Before",tabRect.origin.x);
    tabRect.origin.x = tabRect.origin.x - rect.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%f After", tabRect.origin.x);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{  // animate the following:
        self.toggle.frame = rect; // move to new location
        self.tabButton.frame = tabRect;
    }];
    NSLog(@"%f AfterAnimation", tabButton.frame.origin.x);
```

The toggle view moves fine, but the `tabButton` view does not animate or move. The strange thing is that both the "After" and "AfterAnimation"  debugging code returns the same value, which suggests the frame has indeed moved. Is there a specific reason that this will not work when `toggle` is a `UIView` when it would work as a `UIContainerView`?

Note that if I remove the line

```
self.toggle.frame = rect;
```

`tabButton` will animate correctly, but if I move `toggle`, `tabButton` will not move regardless of whether it is first in the animation block or second.

Edit: I have tried moving them into separate blocks and to change the center point rather than the frame, to no avail. It seems that if the `toggle` view moves, the `tabButton` will not move.

Edit 2: The pictorial evidence.{

In the following screenshots tabButton bg is green and toggle bg is red.

[image: Initial position (<code>toggle</code> is off-screen) correct position]

Above: Initial position (`toggle` is off-screen) correct position

[image: The problem in question <code>toggle</code> is correct <code>tabButton</code> is not]

Above: The problem in question `toggle` is correct `tabButton` is not

[image: When <code>self.toggle.frame = rect</code> is commented out (<code>tabButton</code> correct, <code>toggle</code> not)]

Above: When `self.toggle.frame = rect` is commented out (`tabButton` correct, `toggle` not)
}

Edit 3: It's even worse than I feared.{

I have done a few more tests and even if I take the `toggle` change out of the animation block to make it an instant thing, the `tabButton` will *still* not animate. This makes me think the `tabButton` may just fundamentally dislike the `toggle` view and/or myself so will not move just to spite me.

}

Edit 4:{

If I change the `tabButton` animation to `tabButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)` the View snaps instantly to that location and animates back to its original position in the same time as the animation duration.

}

I better add more bookkeeping/TLDR information in case things aren't clear.

- `toggle` is an instance of `ToggleDraw` which is a subview of `UIView` which I created.
- `tabButton` is a `UIButton` which is part of my IB viewController and a property of the class
- Both `toggle` and `tabButton` are subviews of `self.view`
- The animations will work individually with no modifications to the logic of the rects but will not work if they are animated at the same time
- `toggle` animation seems to take precedence over `tabButton` animation regardless of the order

Comment: As at least a temporary hack, what happens if you put them in separate blocks?

Comment: Still will not work unless the toggle line is commented out

Comment: Interesting.  Can you check the two buttons for any differences in their properties?

Comment: Only one is a button (tabButton), the other is a view that I loaded in from a nib (toggle). Apart from that the properties are more or less identical.

Comment: If you're not changing its size, try moving it by its center point?  `self.toggleButton.center`

Comment: I tried all combinations of moving frame and moving center but the problem persists. If the toggle view moves at all, the tabButton will not animate.

Comment: Is `tabButton` a subView of `toggle`?

Comment: No, both `toggle` and `tabButton` are subviews of `self.view`

Comment: Can you take two screenshots one is before the animation the other is after the animation. Also set `taggle.backgroundColor` with red color, `tabButton` with green color.

Comment: Yep, just edited the question and added the images

Comment: It is weird! I found nothing but an question, you reference tabButton by `self.tabButton`, but in `NSLog(@"%f AfterAnimation", tabButton.frame.origin.x);` you reference it by `tabButton`, maybe this question has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Yeah, switching that all up has no effect on the animation, nor the values being produced in debug code.

Comment: Is there another animation going on, on any of the views? If you mention that the frame is indeed correct after the animation (ie. the values of each view .frame are correct). It could be that you're working with transformed, or layer values changed by another animation.

Comment: The only other animation is the reverse of this (pulls it back to the right) but it is set up in a way that only 1 will ever get called and this also works for the `toggle` view. i.e. it will go from situation in `image 2` to the situation in `image 1`

Comment: Question for you are you using UIDynamicAnimator else where ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem with the animation of an UIView created in IB (the animation didn't start from the current position of the view, and ended in the initial position).

All worked fine after sending layoutIfNeeded() to the underlaying view before the animation block:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
...
```

Comment: It worked best for me if I put it in the animation block in Swift 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem about a UIView Animation. Maybe your toggle posiztion is related to your tabButton. For a try, your can set toggle frame to a rect lick (10, 10, 100,100), then check the result.

Comment: I tried this out, the animation essentially went in reverse for no reason in particular

Comment: the toggle's subviews contian tabButton?

Comment: Nope, the views are siblings. Both are subViews of self.view

Answer (score 0):

I've created an example of what you describe and everything seems to work fine. This is what I used:

```
UIView *toggle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 64, 100, 100)];
[toggle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:toggle];

UIButton *tabButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 64, 100, 100)];
[tabButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.view addSubview:tabButton];

CGRect rect = toggle.frame;
CGRect tabRect = tabButton.frame;
rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x - rect.size.width;
NSLog(@"%f Before",tabRect.origin.x);
tabRect.origin.x = tabRect.origin.x - rect.size.width;
NSLog(@"%f After", tabRect.origin.x);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{  // animate the following:
    toggle.frame = rect; // move to new location
    tabButton.frame = tabRect;
}];
```

What I can suggest is to make sure that the code is being ran on mainthread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.toggle.frame = rect; // move to new location
        self.tabButton.frame = tabRect;
    }];
});
```

Also take into account that the log you have after the animation code is incorrect as it won't run after the animation, but rather right next to asking for the animation.

If you want code to run after the animation you should use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    self.toggle.frame = rect; // move to new location
    self.tabButton.frame = tabRect;
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"Finished animating!");
}];
```

Comment: Is this with `tabButton` being a `UIButton` and `toggle` being a `UIView`? I put a view in the same Rect as tabButton and the view moved just fine.

Comment: I just edited, adding what I used for testing. Everything works fine. Usually when I experience this strange animation behavior it is almost always related to code being ran on a background thread rather than the main one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. If I initialise the `UIButton` (`tabButton`) programmatically rather than through the interface builder, both views will animate simultaneously.

This however seems very *hacky* to me, kind of like putting a bandaid over a missing foot and hoping it will sort itself out.
I could not work out the root cause of the problem but at least I could avoid the symptoms.

If anyone knows why the views would not animate when the button was made in the interface builder post an answer here, I am interested in knowing the reason behind this.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Question for you are you using UIDynamicAnimator else where ?